# not reading file line by line

Tags: c++

So i need to read n numbers from a file and print on screen only those that are prime. The code to determine if a number is prime is working but after it checks a number it doesn't want to check  the other n numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
 int n = 0;
 unsigned int x = 0;

cout << "n= ";
cin >> n;

ifstream f("numbers.txt");

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    int p = 1;
    f >> x;

        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (x == 2)
                cout << x << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 3; i <= x / 2; i++)
            {
                if (x%i == 0)
                    p = 0;
            }
            if (p == 1)
                cout << x << endl;
        }
        cout << "i= " << i << "x= " << x<<endl;
}



f.close();
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

the file is

```
53
34
65
234
756
342
988
997
1
2
97
234
87
234
867
37
234
```

and this is a test of the output to a file since i can't post images

```
53
i= 1x= 53
i= 2x= 34
i= 3x= 65
i= 4x= 234
i= 5x= 756
i= 6x= 342
i= 7x= 988
```

Comment: Maybe because you entered `7` when the program asked for `n`.

Comment: oh this code hurts.

I don't know if this is your issue but you have two for(int i ..)'s those variables will conflict, make one for(int s .. or something.

Comment: At the beginning you said you have to print only the prime numbers, and the code that tests the primality works but it stops after the first one. In the output you show, instead, you are printing all the numbers (including non-primes), and you are not stopping after the first one. So what is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file by this way :

```
std::ifstream f("your_file_name.txt");
unsigned long int x;
while(f >> x)  // will be 0 when the value can't be read (= at the end of the file)
  if(is_prime(x))
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Note that it's not needed to close the file at the end of the scope. The destructor of `f` will do this job.